# tensorflow TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType':

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I am using tensorflow 2 for timeseries classification with below functional model. However I keep getting error:

> model.fit(X,y,epochs = 10, batch_size = 256)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67
> in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:245
> in 
> num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)).pop()
>
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'NoneType'

Below is my code.Can somebody please help to check what is wrong with this code.

```
X = np.asarray(X).astype('float32').reshape(-1,window_length,features)
y = np.asarray(y).astype('float32').reshape(-1,1,1)

dump(X, 'X.pth')
dump(y, 'y.pth')

X = load('X.pth')
y = load('y.pth')

METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
]

y_ = y.reshape(-1)
total = y_.shape[0]
zero_count = sum(y_==0)
one_count = sum(y_==1)

weight_for_0 = (1/zero_count)*(total/2)
weight_for_1 = (1/one_count)*(total/2)

sample_weights = np.ones((y_.shape[0],1))
sample_weights[np.where(y_ == 0)] = weight_for_0
sample_weights[np.where(y_ == 1)] = weight_for_1


size = 128
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(window_length, features))
x = LSTM(size)(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

y = Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(inputs)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 5, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = Conv1D(128, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(y)

x = concatenate([x, y])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs, out)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics=METRICS)
model.fit(X,y,epochs = 10, batch_size = 256, sample_weight = sample_weights)
model.save('model.h5')
```

Comment: Something tells me that one of your `X` or `y` is empty.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `Model.fit`? What does it tell you about the expected types and values for its parameters? Did you try to check the arguments being passed, to make sure they meet those requirements? Do they? You have been using the site for many years, so you should understand by now [the expectation to try to understand the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and some [fundamental technique](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for doing so. If you did try, your question should at least reflect that.

Comment: With same X and Y I am able to run successfully on keras.sequential model. This is the first time I am trying functional model.I am assuming it is related something to keras functional model.

I think it is because y is used 2 times...I think I should rename it to something else.

Comment: yes it is because of y usage 2 times after renaming 1 instance of y the code runs fine.